# How to trigger function when @keyup.delete input until it is empty? VueJS

Tags: javascript, input, vuejs2

In my DOM I have an input area, enter it with some text to insert a tag

<input @keyup.delete="inputBackspace()" @keyup.enter="insert_tag()">

and here is my methods

```
insert_tag() {
  let value = this.tagInput
  this.tags.push(value)
  this.tagInput = ''
},
inputBackspace() {
  if (this.tagInput === '') this.tags.splice(-1, 1)
}
```

But the above method is not the result I want, it triggers splice function when the tag is instantly empty by entering backspace.
I prefer to enter backspace to let the input value become empty first, after that enter backspace again to trigger the splice function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your event handler from keyup to keydown, like this `@keydown.delete = "inputBackspace ()"`

Here is my sandbox for this example https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-merkle-nhtl8?file=/src/App.vue